# Neteller REST Api example with PHP

Tags: php, rest

Please share a code for receiving payments with Neteller Rest API.

I could manage to get accessToken from Oauth2, but the rest of my calls return with an error 400, Bad request.

Here is how I get accessToken using Guzzle:

```
$request = $client->post('https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/oauth2/token', [
    'headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $client_secret)],
    'body' => ['grant_type' => 'client_credentials'],
    'allow_redirects' => false
]);

$response = $request->json();
$accessToken = $response['accessToken'];
```

but following code gives me error:

```
$request = $client->post('https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/transferIn', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'body' => [
        'paymentMethod' => [
            'type' => 'neteller',
            'value' => 'netellertest_eur@neteller.com'
        ],
        'transaction' => [
            'merchantRefId' => 'P54bd91375d4fe',
            'amount' => '5000',
            'currency' => 'USD'
        ],
        'verificationCode' => '234124'
    ]
]);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please share a code if you have one for receiving payments.

Cheers,
Al

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to send post fields in the body instead of the JSON which the API expects. As a fairly raw example, something closer to this should work:

```php
$request = $client->post('https://test.api.neteller.com/v1/transferIn', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ],
    'body' => '{
       "paymentMethod": {
          "type": "neteller",
          "value": "netellertest_eur@neteller.com"
       },
       "transaction": {
          "merchantRefId": "P54bd91375d4fe",
          "amount": 5000,
          "currency": "USD"
       },
       "verificationCode": "234124"
    }'
]);
```

Naturally you'll want to use something like `json_encode` to build your body once you're ready  to integrate the code into your application.

Comment: I was having the exact same issues today. I find it really weird that you have to pass the body as a string... If I had to do json_encode myself why bother using an external library instead of just `curl`?

Comment: For very simple examples like this you might not find much difference using Guzzle, but it provides a lot of functionality and convenience once you start doing more (logging, error handling, re-usability) http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/